# How to efficiently enumerate all valid propositional formulas from implicational fragment of intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, algorithms, intuitionistic-logic, decidability

A set of valid Propositional logic formulas is decidable. A set of [implicational propositional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicational_propositional_calculus) formulas is a subset of this set. If we limit Axiom schemas by removing Axiom schema 3 (Peirce's law) we get an implicational fragment of propositional intuitionistic logic.

Based on my reading about [Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) this set is isomorphic to a set of types in Simply typed lambda calculus / Combinatory logic.

How to enumerate this set?

I suppose it is possible to list all propositional formulas: ${a, a\rightarrow a, a \rightarrow b, a\rightarrow a\rightarrow a,...  ((a → b) → a) → a), ...}$ and use SAT solver to check validity. How to filter formulas that are valid due to Peirce's law? Are there SAT solvers that validate only propositional intuitionistic logic?

Is there a more efficient procedure to enumerate this set? The size of all formulas grows very fast ((n^n)*(Number of binary trees of size n)).

Comment: Not sure about this parituclar case, but note that a complete and consistent theory (as the Presburger arithmetic) need not have an efficient decision method (In the Presburger arithmetic , the needed effort to decide a statement grows double exponential with its length, so it is useless in practice).

Comment: Is there a procedure that enumerates all Theorems in Presburger arithmetic? Enumerates not by listing every possible term, validating and printing only theorems but by creating grammar that contains only theorems?

Comment: I don't know about SAT solvers, but Coq for example has the `tauto` tactic which determines whether a propositional formula is an intuitionistic tautology.  In the LJT* sequent calculus it uses, the rules relevant to the implicational fragment would be just ${\rightarrow}I$, ${\rightarrow}E$ (in the sense $A, A \rightarrow B, \Gamma \vdash p$ reduces to $A, B, \Gamma \vdash p$), and what I think of as ${\rightarrow}{\rightarrow}E$: $(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow C, \Gamma \vdash p$ can be proved by branches $A,B\rightarrow C,\Gamma\vdash B$ and $C,\Gamma\vdash p$.

Comment: It might also be possible to enumerate the possible "shapes" of a proof in some sequent calculus, and enforce matches between parent and child nodes to get the shape of a generated tautology (or in some cases, it might turn out to be an impossible shape because for example it ends up requiring $(A\rightarrow B) = A$).  And then, apply the usual interleaving process to combine the lists of all fillings-out of those shapes of tautologies.

Comment: Wait. So given an order on WFFs plus a decision procedure for validity in the pure implicational calculus is not an answer to you question? Because your remarks around SAT suggest otherwise. Do you want a "grammar" that only produces valid formulas? Depending on what is meant by "grammar" (a context-free grammar?), that's not possible for all decidable languages. Certainly not for the pure implicational calculus, which is PSPACE-complete. By the way, you can have subsets of decidable languages that are themselves undecidable.

Comment: Yet another possibility that just occurred to me: use the fact that a Hilbert proof system with axioms $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ and $(A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))$ and the modus ponens rule is sound and complete for the implicational fragment of intuitionistic logic.  So, start off with the list of the two axioms, and then repeatedly generate all possible pairs and do refinement/matching to generate new shapes of tautologies, and add those to the list.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Actually, I have started with this approach. A huge part of generated theorems will be duplications ($K = KKK$,..) and not theorems ($SII$ is not a theorem, SII does not have a type, where $I=SKK$). I am interested in some grammar, where all words are theorems. I have found something similar: Logic for Computable Functions: Theorems in the system are terms of a special "theorem" abstract data type. "The general mechanism of abstract data types of ML ensures that theorems are derived using only the inference rules given by the operations of the theorem abstract type."

Comment: If the ML approach is what I think it is (enumerating terms in the untyped lambda calculus, and applying ML's type inference to derive a shape of the type of the term) then that would be similar in principle to the sequent calculus approach I mentioned.  It would also have the problem of a lot of terms being invalid (for example, any term which contains $\lambda x . x x$ as a subterm) and probably also the problem of a lot of duplications.  (Though if you forbid terms that have a beta reduction, that might help with the duplication issue, at least a bit.)